# Set spesific size of featured images

Tags: functions, images, post-thumbnails, media

I am trying to reduce the loading speed of my webpage. Google PageSpeed Insights tells me to optimize my images. In the following code, how can I set an image size so that if the uploaded image is 99999x99999px the rendered image is maximum 427px wide?

```
<?php
if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
    echo '<a href="' . get_permalink($post->ID) . '" >';
    the_post_thumbnail();
    echo '</a>';
} else {
    echo '<a href="' . get_permalink($post->ID) . '" ><img src="'. get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/img/fallback-featured-image.jpg" /></a>';}
    ?>
```

I would like Wordpress to handle this automatically so that I do not have to worry about cropping my images before I upload. It is also always nice to have the original size, but We do not want the user to wait for such a large image to load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your functions.php you want to issue a call to set_post_thumbnail_size()

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/set_post_thumbnail_size

As with add_image_size, you provide the target width, height & whether you want the image hard cropped to these dimensions.  So, for example,

```
set_post_thumbnail_size(427, 427, true);
```

will crop all your thumbnails to be a maximum of 427px high or wide, depending on aspect ratio of the original.

If you use

```
set_post_thumbnail_size(427, 9999);
```

then your images will be scaled to 427px wide without being cropped.

Comment: Thanks but, will this affect the code I posted? How can I get this to affect the code?

Comment: You put that line into your theme's functions.php and that tells WP to create a version of your image at that size when you upload a new image.  It also tells WP to use that size whenever you call the_post_thumbnail() so your posted code won't need changing.

You _will_ need to tell WP to remake any images that you've uploaded.  I use the Regenerate Thumbnails plugin, but there are others.  https://en-gb.wordpress.org/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/

Comment: Just in case anybody else finds this I just wanted to say that I also had to use the `add_image_size` function

Comment: Interesting. You shouldn't need to. Did you use add_theme_support?